# Replication exception with WebSphere 7 sessions

Tags: jsf, websphere, session-state, websphere-7, session-replication

I have a JSF 2 + Spring 3 application that's currently being deployed to a clustered WebSphere 7 environment. The servers are configured for memory-to-memory replication for session handling. While running tests on the application, a common exception that's being generated is the following:

```
[1/3/12 20:34:48:784 EST] 0000003c WASSession    E MTMBuffWrapper storeObject SESN0200E: Caught Exception while trying to serialize.
[1/3/12 20:34:48:785 EST] 0000003c WASSession    E MTMHashMap handlePropertyHits SESN0202E: Failed to replicate attribute com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.LogicalViewMap
```

Any idea as to what this means and how to resolve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All objects on the session have to be [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) for memory-to-memory replication (or database persistence) to work. Apparently the specified one is not.

(Hint, you can usually Google on the specific error code, which usually will send you to one of [the official WebSphere InfoCenter pages](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.messages.doc/com.ibm.ws.session.resources.WASSession.html).)